# Where to find the list of Check IDs for SuppressMessage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, suppress-warnings, visual-studio-mac

Where can I find the list of Check IDs for `SuppressMessage`?

The code below is an excerpt from Microsoft online document about `SuppressMessageAttribute.CheckId`. I want to know the list of valid values for `SuppressMessage` such as the pair of `"Microsoft.Performance"` and `"CA1804:RemoveUnusedLocals"`.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "isChecked")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1804:RemoveUnusedLocals", MessageId = "fileIdentifier")]
static void FileNode(string name, bool isChecked)
{
    string fileIdentifier = name;
    string fileName = name;
    string version = String.Empty;
}
```

I want to suppress the warning *"Use expression body for methods"*, but I have no idea as to what values should be given to `SuppressMessage`.

Code example:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        // This code raises a warning "Use expression body for methods".
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return MyPrivateMethod();
        }

        // This code raises a warning "Use expression body for methods".
        string MyPrivateMethod()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }

        // This code raises a warning "Use block body for methods".
        public string MyMethod2() => MyPrivateMethod2();

        // This code raises a warning "Use block body for methods".
        string MyPrivateMethod2() => "Hello";
    }
}
```

Moving the cursor on a method name will display a warning. The behavior prevents the document comment of the method (if any) from being displayed.

---

Visual Studio Developer Community: [IDE0022 missmatch to IDE description](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24898/ide0022-missmatch-to-ide-description.html)

Comment: Please show us the code that is generating the warning that you are trying to suppress. [mcve]

Comment: @mjwills I added a code example that generates warnings.

Comment: @mjwills Visual Studio for Mac (community), version 7.2.2 (build 11). Move the cursor on a method name and a warning is displayed. The behavior prevents the document comment of the method from being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming you are talking about the tooltips that VS for Mac shows when you hover over some text and not build warnings.

[image: tooltip]

You can see the list of code rule warnings in the preferences dialog in the Text Editor - Source Analysis - C# section.

[image: preferences dialog]

If you uncheck a code rule here it should prevent VS for Mac showing a tooltip in the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `IDE0022` suppresses both *"Use expression body for methods"* and *"Use block body for methods"*.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        [SuppressMessage("ArbitraryCategoryNameSeemsToWork", "IDE0022")]
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return MyPrivateMethod();
        }

        // This code raises a warning "Use expression body for methods".
        string MyPrivateMethod()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }

        // This code raises a warning "Use block body for methods".
        [SuppressMessage("ArbitraryCategoryNameSeemsToWork", "IDE0022")]
        public string MyMethod2() => MyPrivateMethod2();

        // This code raises a warning "Use block body for methods".
        string MyPrivateMethod2() => "Hello";
    }
}
```

I found `IDE0022` in *"[.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference)"*. It seems the warnings are raised by Visual Studio (not by C# compiler or something like it).

I found the list of CheckIds (which start with `CA`) in *"[Code Analysis Warnings for Managed Code by CheckId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380629.aspx)"*.

I found the issue of the loop between *"Use expression body for methods"* and *"Use block body for methods"* is reported in *"[IDE0022 missmatch to IDE description](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24898/ide0022-missmatch-to-ide-description.html)"* (Visual Studio Developer Community).

I can change the settings of Visual Studio in my local PC to suppress the warnings, but I was searching for a means to suppress them even in others' environment.